# The search box width is increased in the stackexchange.com header

Tags: discussion, support, design, search, stackexchange.com

The width of the search box in the [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/)'s header is increased suddenly.

> [image: stackexchange.com]

Previously in the StackExchange.com, the search box width is less, and there is enough space in the right and left corners of the header (Reference: [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com))

> [image: metastackexchange.com]

If the search box width is not increased intentionally, can this be corrected?

Comment: What's wrong with it? It's consistent with all other SE sites now. If anything, it was a bug before they made it consistent.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard To be consistent with other SE sites, addition of padding to the right and left borders are required, which is similar to MSE.

Comment: There is padding. Maybe your screen is small, and se.com supports bit wider screens, but that's another issue which is not related to the search box width.

Comment: At least it is not [geocitiesized](http://www.wonder-tonic.com/geocitiesizer/content.php?theme=3&music=2&url=stackoverflow.com)